# how to block signals reaching to custom slots

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

blocking signals to reach QObjects is fairly simple with using the `QSignalBlocker Class`

like

```
  # functionality
        self.clickbuton.clicked.connect(self.printsomething)
        self.clickbuton.clicked.connect(self.blockprint)

    def printsomething(self):
        print("dude")

    def blockprint(self):
        self.clickbuton.blockSignals(True)
```

what about custom slots like `def printsomething(self):` ?

trying the same operation but with blocking `def printsomething(self):` from printing

```
 def blockprint(self):
        self.printsomething.blockSignals(True)
```

will give a `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'blockSignals'`

it looks like this method works only for `QObjects` 

how can I block `def printsomething(self):` from printing without using `disconnect` while its connected to the `clicked` signal?

code example

```
"""
Testing Template for throw away experiment

"""


import sys
import os

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg




class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # widget
        self.clickbuton = qtw.QPushButton("click me")

        # set the layout
        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clickbuton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # functionality
        self.clickbuton.clicked.connect(self.printsomething)
        self.clickbuton.clicked.connect(self.blockprint)

    def printsomething(self):
        print("dude")

    def blockprint(self):
        self.printsomething.blockSignals(True)
        # self.m_blocker = qtc.QSignalBlocker(self.clickbuton)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc added

Comment: could you explain what you hope to get, your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Note: A QSignalBlocker blocks an object from emitting a signal, I think you have an XY problem, you could give more detail of the behavior you want to obtain.

Comment: @eyllanesc how can I block `def printsomething(self):` from printing without using `disconnect` when its connected to the buttom clicked signal

Comment: With what you indicate I confirm that you have an XY problem, if you do not want to use disconnect then use a flag, something like: `self._flag = True` on `__init__` and `def printsomething(self):` `if self._flag:` `# foo code`

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to block a slot which is impossible.
You can only block signals of objects inherited from QObject.

As a solution you can instead of

```
def blockprint(self):
        self.printsomething.blockSignals(True)
```

do this

```
def blockprint(self):
        self.blockSignals(True)
```

that would block mainwindow signals until you turn blockSignals flag to false again.